# Is there a way to add a numpy subarray to a given array from a certain index

Tags: python, numpy

Looking for something like

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
B = np.array([5, 7])
print A.add(B, 1) 
[1, 7, 10, 4]
```

potentially choosing axis to add along.

Comment: `A[1:len(B)+1] += B`?

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Kind of slow today.